# Any character including newline - Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I thought it may be `[.\n]+` but that doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The dot cannot be used inside character classes.

See the option [Pattern.DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

> `Pattern.DOTALL` Enables dotall mode. In dotall mode, the expression `.` matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators. Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression `(?s)`. (The s is a mnemonic for "single-line" mode, which is what this is called in Perl.)

If you need it on just a portion of the regular expression, you use e.g. `[\s\S]`.

Comment: Arguably cleaner than `[\s\S]` would be `(?:.|\n)`.  The reason that `[.\n]` doesn't work is that `.` isn't special in character classes; specifying the same thing with a literal or, `|`, works fine.

Comment: @Antal I don't think `(?:.|\n)` is as portable since a new line in Windows is `\r\n`. Maybe `(?:.|\n|\r)`, though now the `\r` is redundant in Unix.

Comment: Good call.  I think the usual solution is `\r?\n`.

Comment: In Java, just do `(?s:`...`)` to enable DOTALL mode for a specific section, and stop worrying about stupid OSs.

Comment: Or, of course, `(?s)`...`(?-s)` to toggle it on then off at those points.

Comment: New URI for Pattern.DOTALL documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Strictly speaking, dot `.` can be used inside character classes, it just doesn't have a special meaning, it just matches a dot.

Comment: Also, use of `[\s\S]` on a CR-LF terminated file could match just one half of a line ending.  Perhaps, `(?:.|\r\n|\r|\n)` would be more precise.

Answer (score 57):

Edit: While my original answer is technically correct, as ThorSummoner pointed out, it can be done more efficiently like so

### `[\s\S]`

as compared to `(.|\n)` or `(.|\n|\r)`

Comment: this appears to be very expensive, `[\s\S]` appears to be a lot kinder on the regex engine anecdotally.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
((.|\n)*)
```

It matches all characters multiple times

Comment: This cause java.lang.StackOverflowError in java. Is there any workaround in java?

Comment: @SudoCoder (?s:.*)