# Regex not working with curly brace

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following pattern:

```
Testcase done, result: {error,
                           {test_case_failed,
                               "Fail: Not all values are as close to expected values."}}
```

Here, I am using the following regex to match the above pattern:

```
Testcase\s+done,\s+result:\s+\{(.*?)\}
```

However, my pattern is not working.

Comment: what regex flavor? have you set the option for `.` to match new lines?

Comment: It's probably the line breaks.

Comment: I am using https://regex101.com/ to test my regex

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
Testcase\s+done,\s+result:\s+\{([\s\S]*?)\}
```

[More info about the . (dot) character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: thanks!! But what is wrong with my expression? How should I use `.* ` to match new line?

Comment: @JohnRambo depends on what language you're using it on.On .NET for example, you have to use [RegexOptions.Singleline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx), while on Java, [Pattern.DOTALL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222649/any-character-including-newline-java-regex) . You can also do a regex that indicates whether it will match a . or a newline in your in environment (\n in Linux, \r\n in Windows) but all in all [\s\S] is a little less of a hassle IMO

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, as I can see you line can either start with Testcase or a blank space and brace' {' or blank space and quote ' {'

```
Regex:
Testcase.*|\ {.*| ".*
```

[Check Here](http://regexr.com/3csrh)