# Remove <div> with a class without removing content

Tags: php, regex, video

I have my videos wrapped in a custom div. It looks like this:-

```
<div class="yt">
  <iframe>....Video code....</iframe>
</div>
```

I want to remove `<div class="yt">` and `</div>` but keep the iframe. I tried using `preg_replace` using this code:-

```
$content = preg_replace('#<div class="yt">(.*?)</div>#', '', $content);
return $content;
```

This removes the whole div. Can somebody help me?

**Desired output**

```
<iframe>....Video code....</iframe>
```

Comment: The most efficient way would be to manually move the children, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript/20910214

Comment: So, I'll have to use JS not PHP? I was wondering if there was a way to do it with PHP.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I've added an answer using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a Regex but you'll have to make two changes:

`(.*?)` doesn't match newline characters. So replace `.` with `[\s\S]` (source: [Any character including newline - Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222649/any-character-including-newline-java-regex))

And to preserve the contents you need to replace it with your capturing group `$1`.

Final code:

```
$content = preg_replace('#<div class="yt">([\s\S]*?)</div>#', '$1', $content);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oHiPt2/1

You could improve the regex or use `trim()` if you need to remove the surrounding white space.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot, Thomas :)

Comment: $content = preg_replace('#<div class="yt">([\s\S]*)</div>#', '$1', $content); // This one will work better. Because with "?" will be removed first "</div>", not the latest. Not tested.